# Magit: show ignored files

Tags: magit

Is there a way to get the output of `git status --ignored` in a Magit buffer? Preferably in a way that would make opening ignored files easy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can customize `magit-status-sections-hook`, functions in this hook are used to insert contents at magit status buffer.

```
;; Command to list ignored files:
;; $ git ls-files --others --ignored --exclude-standard --directory
(defun magit-ignored-files ()
  (magit-git-items "ls-files" "--others" "--ignored" "--exclude-standard" "-z" "--directory"))

(defun magit-insert-ignored-files ()
  (-when-let (files (magit-ignored-files))
    (magit-insert-section (ignored)
      (magit-insert-heading "Ignored files:")
      (magit-insert-un/tracked-files-1 files nil)
      (insert ?\n))))
```

then add `magit-insert-ignored-files` to `magit-status-sections-hook`, it should be very easy if using Custom. I added it right after the "Untracked files" section:

[image]

Comment: Oops, what version of Magit do I need for this to work? I've tried now and it removed the branch information from the status.

Comment: PS. When I change the order of hooks to put `magit-insert-status-headers` in the first position, then the branch information is displayed.

Comment: @wvxvw I am not sure, but it works good here by using latest version from Melpa (`20161105.1602`) and from Melpa-stable (`2.8.0`).

Comment: The behavior I'm seeing is in version 20151211.2221. I'll update then and will see.